# Ruby: Wait for all threads completed using join and ThreadsWait.all_waits - what the difference?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider the following example:

```
threads = []

(0..10).each do |_|
  threads << Thread.new do
    # do async staff there
    sleep Random.rand(10)
  end
end
```

Then there is 2 ways to wait when it's done:

1. Using join:

   ```
   threads.each(&:join)
   ```
2. Using `ThreadsWait`:

   ```
   ThreadsWait.all_waits(threads)
   ```

Is there any difference between these two ways of doing this?

I know that the `ThreadsWait` class has other useful methods. 
And asking  especially about `all_waits` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thwait/rdoc/ThreadsWait.html#method-c-all_waits) clearly states that `all_waits` will execute any passed block after each thread's execution; `join` doesn't offer anything like this.

```
require "thwait"

threads = [Thread.new { 1 }, Thread.new { 2 }]

ThreadsWait.all_waits(threads) do |t|
  puts "#{t} complete."
end # will return nil

# output:
# #<Thread:0x00000002773268> complete.
# #<Thread:0x00000002772ea8> complete.
```

To accomplish the same with `join`, I imagine you would have to do this:

```
threads.each do |t|
  t.join
  puts "#{t} complete."
end # will return threads
```

Apart from this, the `all_waits` methods eventually calls the `join_nowait` method which processes each thread by calling `join` on it.

Without any block, I would imagine that directly using `join` would be faster since you would cut back on all `ThreadsWait` methods leading up to it. So I gave it a shot:

```
require "thwait"
require "benchmark"

loops = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    loops.times do
      threads = [Thread.new { 2 * 1000 }, Thread.new { 4 * 2000 }]
      threads.each(&:join)
    end
  end

  x.report do
    loops.times do
      threads = [Thread.new { 2 * 1000 }, Thread.new { 4 * 2000 }]
      ThreadsWait.all_waits(threads)
    end
  end
end

# results:
# user       system     total       real
# 4.030000   5.750000   9.780000  ( 5.929623 )
# 12.810000  17.060000  29.870000 ( 17.807242 )
```

Comment: FYI removed from stdlib in ruby 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Using map instead of each, will wait for them as it needs their values to build the map.

```
(0..10).map do |_|
  Thread.new do
    # do async staff there
    sleep Random.rand(10)
  end
end.map(&:join).map(&:value)
```