# join threads in the order they finish, in order to raise exception faster

Tags: ruby, multithreading, deadlock

I have a couple threads running and want to wait for them to finish:

```
[thread_a, thread_b].each(&:join)
```

Say that one of the threads suffers an immediate fatal exception as soon as it's started.  Meanwhile, the other takes 10 minutes to complete.  If we're lucky and `thread_a` is the thread that fails, we'll get its exception immediately, since it's being joined first.  However, if we're unlucky, we have to wait 10 minutes for `thread_a` to finish, and only then does `thread_b` get to raise its exception to the parent thread.

I have an existing solution that uses an `ensure` block in each thread, to insert that thread into a queue when it exits.  The parent thread can then poll the queue and join each thread as it finishes.  However, I'm wondering if Ruby has a more idiomatic way to handle this?

Existing solution:

```
dead_threads = Queue.new

threads = 2.times.map do |i|
  Thread.new do
    begin
      case i
      when 0; sleep
      when 1; raise "I'm the problem thread!"
      end
    ensure
      dead_threads << Thread.current
    end
  end
end

live_threads_count = threads.size
until live_threads_count == 0
  dead_threads.shift.join
  live_threads_count -= 1
end
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400319/ruby-wait-for-all-threads-completed-using-join-and-threadswait-all-waits-what? It's possible that the [ThreadsWait](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thwait/rdoc/ThreadsWait.html) class has something you can use.

Comment: can you show your existing solution?

Comment: `ThreadsWait` is exactly what I was looking for -- feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: existing solution added