# Ruby `Thread#join` vs. `ThreadsWait.all_waits`

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have a file `test.rb` with the following code, which increments a shared variable from different threads:

```
require 'thwait'                                                                                                                                                                              

threads_number = ARGV.first.to_i                                                                                                                                                              
incr_number = ARGV.last.to_i                                                                                                                                                                  

start = Time.now                                                                                                                                                                              
sum = 0                                                                                                                                                                                       

create_thread = proc do                                                                                                                                                                       
  Thread.new { incr_number.times { sum += 1 } }                                                                                                                                               
end                                                                                                                                                                                           

threads = threads_number.times.map { create_thread.call }                                                                                                                                     
ThreadsWait.all_waits(*threads)                                                                                                                                                               

p Time.now - start, sum
```

I tried this code on the same computer with different ruby versions, and got the following results:

- ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

  ```
  $ ruby multithreading.rb 4 100000
  0.022668827
  400000
  ```
- jruby 9.2.4.1 (2.5.0) 2018-11-28 f487d1e OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13 on 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13 +jit [linux-x86_64]

  ```
  $ ruby multithreading.rb 4 100000
  0.095028
  241229
  ```

I understand that ruby 2.5 will always give `400000` as the sum because of GIL, and `jruby`'s result can differ because of multithreading.

1. Why ruby 2.5 is faster in that case? Shouldn't jruby be faster than ruby 2.5?
2. What is the difference between `Thread#join` and `ThreadsWait.all_waits`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400319/ruby-wait-for-all-threads-completed-using-join-and-threadswait-all-waits-what

Comment: Have you tried comparing the performance of a single-threaded script between YARV and jruby? I wouldn't be surprised if the difference is significant.